# Floated middle tab in react navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

[image]

I want make bottom tab design like this, Any help/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You can create a custom component for the bottom tab bar. Follow this instruction: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one very useful git repo for this kind of customization, [here](https://github.com/alex-melnyk/clipped-tabbar) is it